# Prove that the following set is enumerable using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

it's my first time posting here.

I'm trying to do the following exercise:

Prove that if A is enumerable, then the set of n-tuples is enumerable.

A = $A^n = {(a_1, a_2,...,a_n) a_j \in A}$

I have to prove it using induction.

Comment: What have you tried so far? People will be more likely to help you if you post your efforts.

Comment: When you say 'enumerable', do you mean 'countable'?

Comment: Yeah, by "enumerable" I mean countable. So far I've tried to check if exists a surjection between the two sets, I've started it but I couldn't finish because I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Enumerable does not mean countable.  Most countable sets are not enumerable.

Comment: You're right, I was reading the material that I have here, it says that enumerable is something that can be written in sequence

Comment: @DanielV No, "Enumerable" is a fairly common (but old-fashioned, I would say) synonym for "countable". Maybe you're thinking of "recursively enumerable" or "computably enumerable"? The possibility for such a confusion is one reason why "countable" is a much better term.

Answer (score 1):

$A^1=A$ is countable by hypothesis.
To prove that if $A^n$ is countable then $A^{n+1}=A^n \times A$ is countable you just use this "lemma":

> If $A$ and $B$ are countable then $A \times B$ is countable

You can prove the "lemma" using a Cantor like argument such as the one you use to prove $\mathbb Q$ is countable:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and see if I can check where the induction will come from.